# [solved]windows not showing partition and its contents after install

Tags: partitioning

my previous windows was xp pro 32 sp3  and i didnt had this problem.
after installing windows 8.1 i opened my computer and the D drive was missing.  i installed windows 7 and its still missing.(it goes like this in disk management7: "an normal drive icon" ,  (this here is a empty space bar and D name is also missing)  , Simple , Basic , NTFS , Healthy (System Active, Primary Partition) , capacity: 103gb , free space: 9.58gb , % free: 9% , Fault Tolerence: No, Overhead: 0%
i searched and googled in the internet but i couldn't find a simple solution
i'm currently using 1 hard disk
and i'd appreciate it if someone give me a fine simple solution
sorry for my english

PROBLEM SOLVED: i opened disk management and right clicked on the nameless partition and clicked on change drive letter and path> add> selected E. now my partition is known as E and all of it contents are there.

Comment: Did your Windows 8 installation upgrade to UEFI. That would certainly screw up XP.  My own machine when it was Windows 8 did do the UEFI update.

Comment: i have no idea what you just said, i've updated the question btw

Comment: Windows started using UEFI instead of Legacy BIOS part way through Windows 8. That is what I was referring to. You would see an EFI or UEFI partition in DIsk Management.

Comment: i still have no idea, did you had this same problem after installing windows 8? how did you fix it?

Comment: and no i dont see a EFI or UEFI partition in disk management, theres a recovery partition with no name i think thats pretty normal

Comment: Updating to UEFI is normal and will not cause any issues (not for me)

Comment: well, thanks anyways

Comment: I really cannot help. It would never occur to me to dual boot XP with a modern Operating System. I have XP as a virtual machine.

Comment: Please [do not add "solved" to the title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/355310); and do not post solutions in the question. Take our short [tour] to see how the site is supposed to work. [Post an answer](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/355310).